# Can I simply copy a CC-BY-SA 3.0 work as CC-BY-SA 4.0?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

It is my understanding that since BY-SA 2.0 <sup>[1]</sup>, all CC-BY-SA licenses have included some automatic "or later" clause, which means you can adapt the work and release the result under a later license.

It was recently pointed out to me that copying a work isn't the (necessarily) same as adapting it. Does re-licensing still operate if the work is copied but not modified?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Relevant link:

> Version 2.0 licenses that feature the Share Alike requirement now clarify that derivatives may be re-published under one of three types of licenses: (1) the exact same license as the original work; (2) a later version of the same license as the original work; (3) an iCommons license that contains the same license elements as the original work (e.g. BY-SA-NC, as defined in Section 1 of each license). The version 1.0 licenses required that derivative be published under the exact same license only. Our tweak means much better compatibility across future jurisdiction-specific licenses and, going forward, across versions. Less forking, more fun. (See Section 4b.)
>
> (from "Share Alike Across Borders" in [Announcing (and explaining) our new 2.0 licenses](https://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/4216))

Alternatively, follow the "More info" link that appears in the "same license" tooltip on the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 human readable license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a copy is also a kind of adaptation (opposite is not true, obviously).

And yes you can take a CC-BY-SA 3.0 work and publish your "adaptation" as CC-BY-SA 4.0:

The CC-BY-SA 3.0 license says:

> **You may Distribute** or Publicly Perform **an Adaptation only under the terms of**: (i) this License; (ii) a later version of this License with the same License Elements as this License; (iii) a Creative Commons jurisdiction license (either this or a later license version) that contains the same License Elements as this License (e.g., Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 US)); (iv) **a Creative Commons Compatible License.**

and:

> "Creative Commons Compatible License" means a license that is listed at http://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses that [...]

I turn, http://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses says in its BY-SA Version 3.0 paragraph:

> Your contributions to adaptations of BY-SA 3.0 materials may only be licensed under: BY-SA 3.0, **or a later version** of the BY-SA license. [...]

CC-BY-SA 4.0 is a later version of CC-BY-SA 3.0, so you can redistribute.