# How do I license a work with CC license version X "or later"?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

When licensing software under the GPL, you can (optionally) add an "or later" clause to the license version. So "GPLv2 or later" can be incorporated into a GPLv3 work, for example.

Is there a recommended way to do this for CC licenses? For example, how do I release a work as "CC BY-SA 2.5 or later"?

(I know that certain recombinations of works under different versions of CC licenses are allowed. I am instead looking for a way to explicitly allow wholesale recombination/relicensing as described above.)

Comment: @PatrickHoefler my (limited) understanding is that this is not the same as being able to simply reuse the work under a different license, based on info I haven't yet added to https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3652 but it sounds like maybe I need to do some more reading and clarify what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode) states that "The Adapter’s License You apply must be a Creative Commons license with the same License Elements, this version or later, or a BY-SA Compatible License." Similar clauses can be found since CC 2.0.